# Why can't I select the first item in the side menu?

Tags: codenameone

I have a very simple project with a single form and five commands. I put each command on both the side menu and the overflow menu. They all work fine on the overflow menu, but on the side menu, the first one never works. The other four work fine, but the first command fails. Usually, when I touch it, nothing happens. Occasionally it will get selected, and stay selected until I click another one. But the command never gets executed. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug?

It runs fine on the simulator. It fails on my Android Moto E (2nd Generation) with 4G LTE, running Android 5.1. I haven't run it on any other phone or tablet.

```
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;

@SuppressWarnings("HardCodedStringLiteral")
public class Playground {

  private Form current;
  private MainForm mainForm;
  public void init(Object context) {
    UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
  }

  public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
      current.show();
      return;
    }

    Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
    mainForm = new MainForm();
    Form hi = mainForm;
    hi.show();
    current = hi;
  }

  public void stop() {
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

  private class MainForm extends Form {
    MainForm() {
      super("Test of Hamburger Menu");
      Display.getInstance().setCommandBehavior(Display.COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_BUTTON_BAR_TITLE_RIGHT);
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();
      setToolbar(toolbar);

      Command dummyOne = new PlaygroundCommand("One");
      Command dummyTwo = new PlaygroundCommand("Two");
      Command dummyThree = new PlaygroundCommand("Three");
      Command dummyFour = new PlaygroundCommand("Four");
      Command dummyFive = new PlaygroundCommand("Five");

      toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(dummyOne);
      toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(dummyTwo);
      toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(dummyThree);
      toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(dummyFour);
      toolbar.addCommandToSideMenu(dummyFive);
      toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(dummyOne);
      toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(dummyTwo);
      toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(dummyThree);
      toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(dummyFour);
      toolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(dummyFive);
    }
  }

  private void doCommand(ActionEvent evt) {
    Dialog.show("Command", evt.getCommand().toString(), Dialog.TYPE_INFO, null, "OK", null);
  }

  private class PlaygroundCommand extends Command {
    PlaygroundCommand(String name) {
      super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent evt) {
      doCommand(evt);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
Display.getInstance().setCommandBehavior(Display.COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_BUTTON_BAR_TITLE_RIGHT);
```

We normally initialize the form in the `start` not in the `init` method as it's more of an application flow than an actual initialization. So one of these two things is probably causing this odd behavior.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. That's good to know, although it didn't fix the problem. Now the first menu item usually gets hilighted when I touch it, but it still doesn't execute. I modified the code above to show what the code looks like that I just tested.

Comment: I also tried removing the setCommandBehavior() call completely, but that still didn't fix it.

Comment: I think this relates to special handling of the status bar area. If the first command is very high it can conflict with events that are meant to pull down the status bar area (natively in Android).

Comment: That makes sense. In my experiments, I have since discovered that if I aim for the very bottom of that first item, I can sometimes activate it. (I'm using a theme where I've enlarged the size of the menu items.)

Comment: We were able to reproduce this but I'm not sure if this is something we can/should solve. The top area of the device is reserved in most OS's (both iOS and Android) so you shouldn't really place anything there. The right fix is to have better sizing/padding by default to the `SideCommand` UIID.